# Exposed drop down menu in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-dropdownmenu

[image: Drop down menu]
[image: Exposed drop down menu]

Hi, I need help. How to make drop down menu like on photos? Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the standard `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` provided by M3.

Something like:

```
    val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }

    val shape = if (expanded) RoundedCornerShape(8.dp).copy(bottomEnd = CornerSize(0.dp), bottomStart = CornerSize(0.dp))
           else RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
    ) {

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),
            textStyle = TextStyle.Default.copy(
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                fontWeight=  FontWeight.Light),
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text("Unit of length", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, ) },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            shape = shape,
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(
                focusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Transparent
            )
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(selectionOption) },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                        expanded = false
                    },
                    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried to make it with Exposed Dropdown Menu, but I didn't find right way how to rounded all corners and after expanded rounded only two top corners and two bottom corners not in the middle.

Comment: @HighBinder I've updated the answer with shape based on the expanded state.

Comment: it looks great, but is there any option to change animation of exposed drop down menu? Thanks :)

Comment: @HighBinder As far as I know it is defined internally.

Comment: Don't we need a `menuAnchor`, if so which gradle dependency is that?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky M3 1.0.0